# Creating a Pivot table which recieves data from a cell and filters accordingly

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("J2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewPolicy As Double

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Payment Data").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("POL_NUMBER")
NewPolicy = Worksheets("Payment Data").Range("J2").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewPolicy
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Apologizes for any incorrect syntax as I am a novice at this. In the above code, I am trying to get A Pivot table to receive a value from a cell in the same page and then update itself instantaneously, without any need to interact with the referenced cell. I got this code from a website and I tailored it but I am unable to get the Pivot table to update. Before changing this code to the above state, my code looked like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("J2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewPolicy As Double

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets("Payment Data").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("POL_NUMBER")
NewPolicy = Worksheets("Payment Data").Range("J2").Value

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewPolicy
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

In its old state, the code worked but I had to click on J2 and click elsewhere on the sheet (J2 gets its value from a cell in another sheet which is the main data entry sheet). 
I don't want to have to keep clicking on J2 to get the Pivot table to update. I want it to update as soon as J2 changes its value based on another cell value in another sheet (J2 and that other cell in connected).

Thanks in advance,
LHS

Comment: So what happens with this code exactly?

Comment: The code at the very top is the code that I am using. What the code does is that it receives a value from a cell in the worksheet (the cell itself receives its the value from another cell in another worksheet. 
I want the code to detect a change in the value of the cell and then filter the pivot table accordingly. 
But now, nothing happens. The code is just dead.

Comment: How are you changing J2?

Comment: The second set of code at the bottom works unlike the first. But the issue is that once the referenced cell receives the value, I need to go to the worksheet and click on the referenced cell and click elsewhere for the pivot table to receive the value from the referenced cell. Now as I told before, the referenced cell itself is connected to another cell in another sheet. What I really what is when I enter the value in the input sheet, with the instantaneous change in the reference cell, the pivot table should filter accordingly without me have to abandon the input sheet.

Comment: J2 is the referenced cell that is connected by reference to the a cell in the input worksheet.

Comment: If it contains a formula, it won't trigger a change event. You should either use the Calculate event or the change event on the input sheet.

Comment: The code at the top is my attempt using change. But still it is not working. J2 only has a cell reference, no formula. Also calculate does not work on the current code.

Comment: What exactly is in J2. If it starts with `=` it is a formula and it **will not trigger a Change event.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need code to do this if you have Excel 2010 or later, because:

- a PivotTable with nothing but one field in the Filters pane looks and
  behaves pretty much exactly like a Data Validation dropdown does; and
- that PivotTable can be hooked up to the other PivotTables via
  slicers, so that it controls them.

Here's how that looks, when implemented. That Region dropdown at the the top is just a PivotTable with nothing but the Region field displayed, as a Page Field. The other two Pivots are connected to it via a slicer.

[image: Faux DV and Pivot]

And now, if you change that Region selection, the other pivots get updated automatically:

[image: Pivots are synced]

Of course, you could just use a slicer directly:

[image: Just use a slicer]

See http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/